# Структура хранения unit-тестов в Django-проекте

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, django

Задался вопросом покрытия unit-тестами кода. В питоне с этим не особо работал до этого. Погуглив, не могу определиться, какой вариант правильный (сомневаюсь между двумя). В Java-проектах встречал следующий подход:

```
src-|
    |-main
        |-com.trolololo.foo
    |-test
        |-com.trolololo.foo
```

То есть, есть директория с кодом, есть параллельная директория с тестами, и в ней повторяется структура основной директории от корня.

Погуглив, нашёл такой пример для питона - тесты ложатся в пакет с основным кодом, в файл **tests.py** или пакет **tests**. Для Django видел примеры, когда в каждом аппликейшене в корне создаётся файл/пакет tests, и всё пишется туда. Но вот не совсем понимаю, как быть при более сложной структуре.

Итак, есть 2 варианта. 
Вариант №1 - по аналогии с Java-проектами, но повторяется структура не проекта, а в рамках аппликейшена:

```
project
    |- app1
        |- services
            |- foo.py
            |- bar
                |- qwe.py
        |- models.py
        |- views.py
        |- tests
            |- test_models.py
            |- test_views.py
            |- services
                    |- test_foo.py
                    |- bar
                        |- test_qwe.py
```

Вариант №2 - создавать файл **tests.py**, либо пакет **tests** рядом с кодом:

```
project
    |- app1
        |- services
            |- foo.py
            |- foo2.py
            |- bar
                |- qwe.py
                |- test_qwe.py
            |- tests
                    |- test_foo.py
                    |- test_foo2.py
        |- models.py
        |- views.py
        |- tests
            |- test_models.py
            |- test_views.py
```

Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: Здесь не может быть правильных или неправильных вариантов: структурирование тестов точно такая же задача, как и структурирование основной кодовой базы. Всё на ваш вкус.

Comment: Можно взять за основу рекомендацию Django [testing-reusable-applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#testing-reusable-applications)

Answer (score 0):

```
runtests.py
app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    ...
app2/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    test_settings.py
    tests.py
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).